# Automatically download new Youtube videos

Tags: automation, youtube, podcast

I am looking for a way to automatically download new Youtube videos from all my subscriptions or from a certain user/channel to my Android phone for later offline viewing. Some sort of video podcast functionality.

I tried a lot of different methods which I read on the web, but none of them seem to work. I first looked in the official Youtube app. You can see your subscriptions there, but no possibility to automatically download new videos for offline viewing. Next step was using a podcast app (AntennaPod) and a url generated from Youtube api:

`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/simonscat/uploads?alt=rss&orderby=published`

This did not work, it just downloaded a small summary and a link to the video. After trying this, I used the YTPodcaster website to generate a podcast link:

`http://ytpodcaster.com/api/index.php/rss?youtubeid=simonscat&quality=22`

Sadly, also this did not work. Latest episodes seemed to be downloading, but when I opened one it just returned "null".
I tried other podcast apps (BeyondPod, Podcast Addict, DoggCatcher) but none of them seem to be able to automatically download Youtube videos.

Does anybody know a solution for this?

(Using Android 4.4.2 on Xperia T)